# How to Use AWS S3 Transfer Acceleration with Magento 2's Remote Storage Configuration?

Tags: magento2, aws, s3

I'm using Magento 2 and I've set up AWS S3 as a remote storage solution for my media files. However, I've noticed that the upload speeds are slower than expected. I want to enable AWS S3 Transfer Acceleration to improve the upload and download speeds.
Here is my current remote storage configuration in env.php:

```
'remote_storage' => [
'driver' => 'aws-s3',
'config' => [
    'bucket' => '*****-uat-new-ui',
    'region' => 'ap-south-1',
    'credentials' => [
        'key' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
        'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
    ]
]
```

],

My Transfer Acceleration URL is https://****-uat-new-ui.s3-accelerate.amazonaws.com.

Can anyone guide me on how to properly configure Magento 2 to make use of the S3 Transfer Acceleration feature? Specifically, what changes do I need to make in my env.php file or elsewhere?

Thank you in advance for your help!